# How to get fewer ttys with Systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd, console

In the old days I just modified `/etc/inittab`. Now, with systemd, it seems to start tty[1-6] automatically, how should I disable tty[4-6]?

Looks like there's only one systemd service file, and it use a `%I` to discern different tty sessions. I hope I don't need to remove that service, and create each `getty@ttyX.service` manually.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no real need to disable "extra" TTYs as under `systemd` gettys are generated on demand: see `man  systemd-getty-generator` for details. Note that, by default, this automatic spawning is done for the VTs up to VT6 only (to mimic traditonal Linux systems).

As [Lennart says in a blog post](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> In order to make things more efficient login prompts are now started on demand only. As you switch to the VTs the getty service is instantiated to getty@tty2.service, getty@tty5.service and so on. Since we don't have to unconditionally start the getty processes anymore this allows us to save a bit of resources, and makes start-up a bit faster.

If you do wish to configure a specific number of gettys, you can, just modify `logind.conf` with the appropriate entry, in this example 3:

```
NAutoVTs=3
```

<sup>1. In fact the entire series of posts—currently numbering 18— [systemd for Administrators](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-1.html), is well worth reading.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jason. My company's application is shipped on a physical server and on older distributions we would modify inittab to lock out other ttys.

Answer (score 12):

On Debian-based systems, there is a file that causes 5 extra getty's to be launched on startup if you've just built a server (without dbus service):

```
/lib/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty-static.service
```

In it, it says:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/systemctl --no-block start getty@tty2.service getty@tty3.service getty@tty4.service getty@tty5.service getty@tty6.service
RemainAfterExit=true
```

Just deleting this file will stop the extra getty's from spawning.  Feel free to shorten the list if you want to just spawn one extra getty (for 2 virt consoles).  Note that you automatically get one on tty1 so you always have at least one virtual console.

See also: [systemd-logind.service fails to start if dbus is missing](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=772700)

Comment: NB: the file is owned by the systemd package, so to modify or delete it, use `dpkg-divert` first. But, there's also a systemd-native way to get it out of the way - run `sudo systemctl mask getty-static.service` and set up your own in `/etc`

Comment: `mask`ing an enabled service is [noisy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369713/removing-debian-package-automatically-masks-systemd-service-causes-a-systemd-w), it would be cleaner to create a unit with the same name in `/etc` to override it's contents.  Use ExecStart=/bin/true if you desire to start zero static getty's.

Comment: the other systemd correct way is to override the package version (you really should NEVER delete that file) using `sudo systemctl edit getty-static.service`, which will create an override file that takes precedence over the `/lib` one

Answer (score 12):

To disable gettys on particular TTYs 4-6 while possibly leaving 1-3 and 7-9 working, run:

```
for i in {4..6}; do
  systemctl mask getty@tty${i}.service
done
```

`mask` creates symlink `/etc/systemd/system/{name} -> /dev/null` which effectively disables service. Attempt to run it via `systemctl start` will display error `Failed to start NAME.service: Unit NAME.service is masked.`

If you have A.service `Wants=masked.service`, then `start A` will succeed but also generate dependency start error in journal.

If you have B.service `Requires=masked.service`, then `start B` will also fail.

Yup, necroanswer. Cheers.