# Why X server runs on TTY1 and not TTY7 on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, tty

**Edit: it seems Arch now uses TTY7 for X by default, so this question is irrelevant**

I've used Debian derivates (*buntu, CrunchBang), Mandriva, OpenSuSE, Fedora, name it.. all  of them had X server at TTY7 (at least I think it was 7), accessed with:

```
Ctrl + Alt + F7
```

Now, I moved to Arch, and it's on TTY1 now -

```
Ctrl + Alt + F1
```

All the others are regular TTY's with login prompt.

Why is that? Is it perhaps because Arch uses Systemd?

Comment: It depends on how you start X.

Comment: Someone once asked Spike Milligan “what are you doing here”, he answered “everyone has to be somewhere”.

Comment: A better question may be “how do I move it to tty7”?

Comment: This is a good question, although richard is right in the sense that it's not specific to Arch.  I mostly use fedora (which uses systemd) but I use a non-graphical boot target and `startx` -- then X starts on the same TTY.  But contra @StrongBad my ubuntu and I believe debian installs (which also don't boot to a GUI, i.e., also require `startx`) *do* start on another TTY > 6.  I'm guessing it has something to do with where a (potentially non-existent) display manager is supposed to be.

Comment: Well, I'm mostly surprised by the change. I don't really care what F-key I have to use (that is needed only after I break graphics driver etc). I assumed the TTY7 is sort of a convention or a default X setting or something, so I'm wondering why Arch is different.

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/how-to-get-fewer-ttys-with-systemd

Comment: When `ctrl+alt+f7` does not work, then you  may find `chvt 7` handy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was changed in October 2012 during/after the migration to systemd/logind. According to [a bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/32206), running the X server on a different tty than the active consolekit session caused things to break because the session on (for example) TTY7 would not be authenticated . Without logind, one could use ck-launch-session in `~/.xinitrc` to get a new session for the X server. However, this didn't work anymore with logind, so `/etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` was changed to just start the X server on the current tty.

Comment: Interesting, so basically it's just a workaround for a bug in logind?

Comment: I don't understand the inner workings of *Kit and logind enough to really answer that question but to me it sounds like a reasonable decision to not automatically transfer sessions from one tty to another. And remember, `ck-launch-session` was basically (afaiu) made to work around the same limitation.

Comment: The question is specific to Arch Linux, as is the answer.  People are referring to this from elsewhere as a more general answer, however.  It is not.  The reason that X uses the first virtual terminal on Fedora, for example, _pre-dates the very existence of systemd_ by some years.  This question and answer explicitly limit themselves to Arch.