# Run top instead of getty

Tags: systemd, startup

By default, `systemd` auto-launches `getty` on each VT except VT7. What I would like is for `systemd` to launch `top` on VT6 instead of `getty`. Any idea how I configure it to do that?

Comment: What evidence do you have that systemd auto-launches, why do you think this would be configurable or that you'd be able to change this into an interactive program?. And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Consider, for example, this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/how-to-get-fewer-ttys-with-systemd which explains how to adjust the number of VTs which auto-launch `getty`.

Comment: Or indeed http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do it on `tty6` because:

> **tty6** is especially reserved for auto-spawned gettys and unavailable to other subsystems such as X[3]. This is done in order to ensure that there's always a way to get a text login, even if due to fast user switching X took possession of more than 5 VTs.

For more info you can check [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html).

But you can try this on `tty5` for example. You can create following service (testo.service or whatever you decide) in `/lib/systemd/system/` on most distributions but in `openSUSE` I think it is `/usr/lib/systemd/system`:

```
[Unit]
Description=top on tty5

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/top
ExecStop=/bin/kill -HUP ${MAINPID}
StandardInput=tty
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty5
Restart=always
RestartSec=2

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
```

And then:

```
systemctl enable testo.service
```

Comment: Worked perfectly first time. Well done!

Comment: You've missed the part where you tell `logind` not to attempt to start `autovt@tty5.service` or you tell systemd that this is (an alias for) `getty@tty5.service`.  Also note that if all that one wants to do is change `ExecStart` for one specific instance of the template unit, there's another way to do that.

Comment: @JdeBP i've tested on debian an it worked as expected without additional configuration. Could you elaborate on this so we can improve this answer?

Comment: @JdeBP thanks, I will read and try to edit it tomorrow.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Automatic_login_to_virtual_console for the second part.  `logind` tries to check to ensure that the virtual terminal isn't already in use, but there's a very small window where this can potentially race with another service, depending from exactly how one activates things.  But the alias is *definitely* necessary if one has, say, explicitly instantiated a `getty@tty5.service` or followed something like https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_set_automatic_login_on_a_virtual_console_terminal.3F .

Comment: @JdeBP The systemd documentation says it only tries to auto-launch `getty` if the terminal is otherwise unused. Presumably starting `top` prevents the auto-launch of `getty`. Works on my OpenSUSE box.

Answer (score 1):

What he is trying to do is: have a "top" always available on vt6. Seems like a reasonable goal to me.

The configuration vor the login gettys on the vt's are in 
`/etc/systemd/logind.conf`

Here you can restrict systemd on the usage of login-vt's.

What i don't know at the moment is, how the "inittab" functionallity is handled by current distros. "inittab" is where you would have put such a process ...

Maybe this helps?
Best regards, 
gerhard