# Removing Debian package automatically masks systemd service - causes a systemd warning

Tags: debian, systemd

I booted a Debian unstable container.  Early on, systemd inside the container shows `rsync.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit rsync.service is masked`.

I determined that rsync.service was masked automatically because the rsync package was removed.  Re-installing the package unmasked it again.

1. Is there documentation for this behaviour?
2. What is the conflict that causes systemd to warn, when faced with this behaviour of Debian?
3. I'm pleasantly surprised to see that this behaviour somehow detects if I masked rsync while it was installed, and avoids unmasking it automatically if I remove and reinstall rsync.  How is this implemented??  Are there any more subtle limitations to it?

---

### Discovery of automatic masking on package removal

I knew that rsync had originally been installed, but was now removed.  I removed the mask, and was left with this:

```
$ sudo systemctl status rsync
● rsync.service - LSB: fast remote file copy program daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rsync; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

$ # reset status of all systemd services
$ # DO NOT TRY THIS COMMAND INSIDE A REAL, NON-CONTAINER SYSTEM...
$ # IT DOES NOT GO WELL.
$ sudo systemctl isolate default.target

$ sudo systemctl status rsync
● rsync.service - LSB: fast remote file copy program daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/rsync; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2017-06-07 11:35:27 BST; 1s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 432 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/rsync start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /machine.slice/machine-unstable.scope/system.slice/rsync.service

Jun 07 11:35:27 unstable systemd[1]: Starting LSB: fast remote file copy program daemon...
Jun 07 11:35:27 unstable systemd[1]: Started LSB: fast remote file copy program daemon.
```

This output is misleading.  Debian's `/etc/init.d/rsync` was not starting `rsync --daemon`, because I had not changed the default `RSYNC_ENABLE=false` in `/etc/default/rsync`.  (The init script itself would exit silently in this case; however I believe a systemd boot would show a starting message for it, similar to the log messages shown above).  So the masking was serving a useful purpose here.

(The reason /etc/init.d/rsync remains when the package is removed, is that  initscripts are considered to be user-editable configuration files)

It turns out that if I install rsync again, rsync.service is unmasked.  If I remove it, rsync.service becomes masked again.

I'm pleased to say that if I install rsync, mask it, then remove and reinstall rsync, rsync remains masked.

If I use `apt-get remove --purge rsync` to completely remove it, including residual configuration files, then the mask is removed.

Since I have etckeeper installed, I noticed that complete removal also removes 
`/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rsync.service`, as well as removing the mask (`/etc/systemd/system/rsync.service` -> `/dev/null`).  Neither of these files were owned by the package (`dpkg-query -L rsync`), so it looks like these removals are caused by a package script.

### Software versions

Up to date Debian unstable container.  This question was asked soon before the release of stretch.

Host used systemd-container version 231-15.fc25.

### More context for systemd message "ignoring: Unit rsync.service is masked"

```
$ sudo systemd-nspawn -b -D unstable
Spawning container unstable on /home/nspawn/unstable.
Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
systemd 232 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
Detected virtualization systemd-nspawn.
Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)!

Set hostname to <unstable>.
Failed to install release agent, ignoring: File exists
rsync.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit rsync.service is masked
[  OK  ] Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there documentation for this behaviour?

It is written down.  The pointer as to *why* this is implemented is found in a commit message to a file which was since moved elsewhere...

> I'm pleasantly surprised to see that this behaviour somehow detects if I masked rsync while it was installed, and avoids unmasking it automatically if I remove and reinstall rsync. How is this implemented?? Are there any more subtle limitations to it?

Look hard, and you can still find the [source history](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/init-system-helpers/commit/34f1de71a363168bb62161f9796eb727df8ab797).  It links to an [issue](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=714903), which confirms that masking is used to handle the system V initscripts as best as possible under systemd.

Tangent: there's an unimplemented proposal which would remove the need for this, [#749400 - dh_installinit: disable init scripts on removal of package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=749400).  Not that it's an unambiguously good idea.  IIUC, it loses track of whether the script was enabled by the user.  (Note this is a separate setting for each runlevel, in system V init).

The clue to this was in the package script, which I found at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/rsync.postrm`.

```
## from /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postrm-systemd :

if [ "$1" = "remove" ]; then
    if [ -x "/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper" ]; then
        deb-systemd-helper mask rsync.service >/dev/null
    fi
fi
```

What this does is documented in `man deb-systemd-helper`.  'The "mask" action will keep state on whether the service was enabled/disabled before and will properly return to that state on "unmask".'  It is also commented in  `rsync.postinst`:

```
## from /usr/share/debhelper/autoscripts/postinst-systemd-enable :

# This will only remove masks created by d-s-h on package removal.
deb-systemd-helper unmask rsync.service >/dev/null || true
```

Fedora Linux (version 25) doesn't implement this behaviour.  Arguably because they don't support system V init and had a policy to completely remove the old-style init scripts.  I don't know how they handled this issue during the transition... but they could have ignored it without causing any functional problem.

> What is the conflict that causes systemd to warn, when faced with this behaviour of Debian?

In the general case, masking an enabled service seems a bit suspicious, perhaps?

It looks like the rpm based distributions don't / didn't try to preserve the enabled status of initscripts.  Because they run `checkconf --del` on removal.  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-suse-rpm-see-installation-uninstallation-scripts/

---

The modern Fedora rpms have equivalent-looking code

```
$ rpm -q --scripts rsync
...
    # Package removal, not upgrade 
    systemctl --no-reload disable --now avahi-daemon.socket avahi-daemon.service > /dev/null 2>&1 || :
...
```

I looked at this as I noticed removing rsync-daemon doesn't remove  `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/rsyncd.service`.  <del>Because `systemctl disable` does not currently remove symlinks if they point to a file which has already been removed.</del>  This is a bug specific to the rsync package: the service file is in package `rsync`, but the rpm scripts referring to the service are in package `rsync-daemon`.

Comment: Reported as https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864504.  (And the rsync bug to Fedora, but that's a side issue.)

Comment: No-one seems to have considered the fairly simple mechanism of not fiddling with systemd units at all and just unsetting and setting the owner execute permission bit on the van Smoorenburg `rc` script.

Comment: @JdeBP Oh, I have :).  It seems promising (I haven't tested insserv though!).  But then you're back to - is that a customization that someone can make, and which should be preserved according to Debian Policy?  I read Poettering point it out as a direct equivalent of `systemctl mask`, which is not quite explicitly documented.  Maybe you'd get away with it.  I just think the right way is to admit we grew this pain in the neck.  Patch the systemd-sysv compat layer to respect masks we record in /var/lib/update-rc.d.  Then our extra state isn't in /etc and it's not for the admin to fiddle with.

Comment: [The compatibility mechanism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132) already does the execute permission bit check.