# Specify tty numbers

Tags: ubuntu, tty

As described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1131821/53616) on can change the number of tty. However how can I configure it that I have only tty7,...,tty10 (and tty1 to tty6 are disabled)?

I usually use only tty7 upwards because pressing <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is easier than pressing <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for example from an ergonomic point of view. So tty1 to tty6 are redundant for me.

I am working on ubuntu 18.04 which uses systemd.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267447/307435 seems to address your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot change the number of kernel virtual terminal devices (outwith customizing the kernel).  There are always 63 KVTs in Linux.  It is a misconception to think that you are changing the *terminals*.

You are changing *whether a TUI login service is started* connected to each KVT.  *That* is what `systemd-logind` determines, and which is configurable.

- It is only configurable within `systemd-logind` to the extent of specifying an upper bound on the KVT number for the TUI login services that it activates, which is what the `NAutoVTs` setting is.  So `systemd-logind` itself is only tunable to the extent that you can specify the range, 1–*N*, of TUI login services.  *N* will have to be *at least* 7 for you.
- It is configurable outwith `systemd-logind` somewhat more freely by masking the relevant instantiations of the `autovt@.service` service template.  Thus you can individually thwart `systemd-logind`'s attempts to activate `autovt@tty1.service` through to `autovt@tty6.service` by masking those.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484601/5132