# Questions about tty

Tags: tty, console, virtual-consoles

1. Why are there so many ttys? Are multiple tty necessary?
2. Why are multiple things spread in different ttys? For eg i have the runit logs on tty1, wm on tty7, and a blinking white cursor on the corner of screen on tty8. Why not everything in one tty?
3. Why doesn't linux place these in order - tty1: runit logs, tty2: wm, etc.
4. What does the binking cursor mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are there so many ttys?

In the past there was no graphical subsystem, no apps like `screen`/`tmux`, so multiple consoles allowed to be able to easily switch between multiple running tasks [under multiple users] simultaneously.

> Are multiple tty necessary?

No, you may as well have a single one.

> Why are multiple things spread in different ttys? For eg i have the runit logs on tty1, wm on tty7, and a blinking white cursor on the corner of screen on tty8. Why not everything in one tty?

Historical conventions.

> Why not everything in one tty?

If you have the only console and you run Xorg on top of it, you no longer have this console. In case Xorg misbehaves you're left with a semifunctional system.

> Why doesn't linux place these in order - tty1: runit logs, tty2: wm, etc.

Historical conventions. You may reconfigure everything however you like.

- [How to get fewer ttys with Systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/how-to-get-fewer-ttys-with-systemd)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/getty
- `man 5 logind.conf`
- Where Xorg runs depends on your display manager.

> What does the binking cursor mean?

An unitialized console with no applications running on it.