# How to disable tty's?

Tags: xorg, tty

I want `Ctrl+Alt F*` to do nothing

Currently I go to a tty at F3-F6, the login screen at F1 and the DE at F2.

How to remove that ability?

Comment: So you want to have only one console, the primary one? You want to disable the rest of the ttys and leave only tty1?

Comment: Zero tty's, not even tty1.

Comment: If your init system is systemd, you may find this helpful: [How to get fewer ttys with Systemd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56531/how-to-get-fewer-ttys-with-systemd)

Comment: Note: you can configure your X system not to use use such keys for virtual consoles. I was thinking it was the default for many years.